# Error in pointer arithmetic (OpenCL)

Tags: opencl

Can someone explain me why this code doesn't work?

```
__kernel void foo(__global const void* a)
{
  __global const uchar* currentPosition = (__global uchar*) a;

  // Update the position
  currentPosition += 4;
}
```

When I try to read the value of currentPosition after the increment I get the same result as when I don't do the arithmetic.

Why is this happening?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with reading the value of `currentPosition`: do you mean that you read the value pointed to by `currentPosition` (which shouldn't have changed), or do you mean that `currentPosition` still points to the same memory address (which shouldn't be the case)?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the 'const' keyword where you declare currentPosition. C++ does not allow you to modify values. You already set currentPosition when you declare it.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference for this code. `currentPosition` is declared to point to a `const uchar`, but the pointed to value is never modified, only the pointer itself.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error yesterday at night. The problem was not with the pointer arithmetic but with data alignment in the buffer *a*.

Sorry guys but I'm new in OpenCL :(